# Nginx makes Nuxt automatically redirect to index page

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

The following Nginx config correctly returns `/pages/subdomain/index.vue` when visiting `{tenant}.mysalon.test`.

However **(!)**, after 0.5s it automatically changes the view to `/pages/index.vue`, why?!

The issue dissapears when I remove the second location block `location /_nuxt/ {}`, but without that block I'm not able to access anything within `{tenant}.mysalon.test/_nuxt/`, because the `_nuxt` folder isn't located within `/pages/subdomain/` obviously.

How to solve?

**GIF**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzFEA.jpg

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<tenant>.+)\.mysalon\.test$;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                    x-Tenant $tenant;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000/subdomain/;

    }

    location /_nuxt/ {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                    x-Tenant $tenant;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000/_nuxt/;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137877/reverse-proxy-to-redirect-url-to-subdomain

Comment: Would you found any solution?