# reverse proxy to redirect url to subdomain

Tags: php, nginx, nuxt.js, subdomain, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to rewrite help URL from `example.com/help` to `help.example.come`.
I tried many ways for configuring nginx but When I'm requesting `example.com/help`, for a moment content appears and then it redirect to home page with `help.example.come` url.

I used nuxtjs v2.13.3 and nginx in my work. Here is my nginx conf:

1. nuxtjs server block

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.html;
        root /var/www/site/dist/;
        server_name  example.come;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }
    
    
        # help redirecting...
        location ~ ^/help/(.*)$ {
            return 301 $scheme://help.example.come/$1;
        }
    }
```

2. subdomain server block

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name help.example.come;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/help/;
        }
    
        location /_nuxt/ {
            rewrite /help/(.*) /$1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/_nuxt/;
        }
    
        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
            rewrite ^/_nuxt(/.*) $1;
            root /var/www/site/dist/;
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to be clear. You want to redirect the users inital request on example.com/help to help.example.com and then proxy it to you backend nuxt??? Am I right?

Comment: Yes @TimoStark. Actually I set an specific port for the nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is doing exactly what you need but:

An incomming request on `example.com/help/uri1/uri2` will be redirected to `help.example.com/help/uri1/uri2`

Before we are proxying the request to our backend we are rewriting the request_uri

`rewrite ^/help(.*)$ /_nuxt$1 break;`

Here we are replacing the `/help/` with `/_nuxt/`.

Here is my test configuration:

```
server {                                                                                
    listen 80;                                                                        
    server_name example.com;                                                                                    
    location /help {                                                                    
      #return 301 http://help.example.com$request_uri;
      rewrite ^/help(.*)$ /_nuxt$1 break;                                            
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;                            
    }                                                                                   
}                                                                                       
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
server {                                                                                
                                                                                        
        listen 80;                                                                    
        server_name help.example.com                                                                                
        location / {                                                                    
         rewrite ^/help(.*)$ /_nuxt$1 break;                                            
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;                                             
                                                                                        
        }                                                                               
}                                                                                       
                                                                                        
server {                                                                                
        #Fake Backend                                                                   
                                                                                        
        listen 3000;                                                                    
                                                                                        
        location /_nuxt {                                                               
          add_header "Content-Type" "text/html";                                        
          return 200 "$request_uri \n";                                                 
        }                                                                               
                                                                                        
}
```

My lab request

```
8080 = example.com
8081 = help.example.com
8082 = fake bakend (:*3000)
```

```
root@deploy-VirtualBox:/etc/nginx/conf.d#curl -vL http://192.168.137.129:8080/help/uri1/uri2;
*   Trying 192.168.137.129...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.137.129 (192.168.137.129) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /help/uri1/uri2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.137.129:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.19.3
< Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2020 17:12:59 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: http://192.168.137.129:8081/help/uri1/uri2
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.137.129 left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://192.168.137.129:8081/help/uri1/uri2'
* Found bundle for host 192.168.137.129: 0x55623c402020 [can pipeline]
*   Trying 192.168.137.129...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.137.129 (192.168.137.129) port 8081 (#1)
> GET /help/uri1/uri2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.137.129:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.19.3
< Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2020 17:12:59 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 18
< Connection: keep-alive
<
/_nuxt/uri1/uri2
* Connection #1 to host 192.168.137.129 left intact
```

Comment: Thank Timo for your response. I want that both `help.example.com` and `example.com/help` have same point. but in your answer `help.example.com` and `example.com` are same.

Comment: So you want that help.example.com as well as example.com/help are working in the same way? Send requests to the same backend? But that means also, there will no! redirect from example.com/help to help.example.com: Is this what you need?

Comment: Somehow, yes!  I want `help.example.com` and `example.com/help` requests to the same backend, but also `example.come/help` redirect to `help.example.com` !

Comment: So basically you can not redirect the user and send the response from the backed. I have updated my example. `help.example.com` as well as `example.com/help` are now doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT gonna work, at least in Nuxt 2 (vue-router 3)

In Vue Router, every path has a component, for example:

| Path | Component |
| --- | --- |
| / | pages/index.vue |
| /help | pages/help/index.vue |

When you change the URL from `example.com/help` to `help.example.com/`, the path will change from `/help` to `/` right?

So, the vue-router will render the component of the `/` path and, it's `pages/index.vue` (not `pages/help/index.vue` any more).

But why you see the content appears at the first moment, because of the SSR. The server renders the content, then code from client side works, vue-router on client side works, it will re-render the router-view component.